# Telegram Bot dynamic keyboard in php

Tags: php, telegram-bot

How to create different keyboards for different users,For example user has defined keyboard according to his phone number.(actually I want to limit access the keyboard for users according to their phone number)

Answer (score 0):

Using `selective` [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup) is as close as you can get.